# Value of $n $ th derivative of the function at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $y=\arccos (x)$  where $-1\leq x\leq 1$ then calculate $y_n $ at $x=0$ where $y_k$ is the $kth$ order derivative. $$\text {Attempt} $$ . We have $\cos (y)=x $ thus $-sin (y)y_1=1$ . Differentiating $-cos(y)y_1-sin (y)y_2=0$  But as here all is in $y $ so this isnt very fruitful. Other way is $y_1 (1-x^2)=1$ differentiating $n$ times taking help of leibnitz theorem we have $y_{n+1}=x^2y_{n+1}+2nxy_n+n (n-1)y_{n-1} $ . But how to go from here and generalize some result for $n $? Thanks!

Comment: I can't think of a good way to show this in general, but if you look at the derivatives on wolfram alpha, you will see that the odd derivatives evaluate to -1 and the even derivatives evaluate to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Expand in MacLaurin series. You get

$$\arccos x=\frac{\pi }{2}-\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{x^{2 k+1} \Gamma \left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } (2 k+1) \Gamma (k+1)}$$

compare with the general MacLaurin formula

$$f(x)=f(0)+\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }\dfrac{f^{(k+1)}(0)x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$$

we note that for even values of derivative order $f^{(2n)}(0)=0$ so the previous formula becomes
$$f(x)=f(0)+\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }\dfrac{f^{(2k+1)}(0)x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$

and we can say that
$$\frac{f^{(2k+1)}(0)x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}=\frac{x^{2 k+1} \Gamma \left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } (2 k+1) \Gamma (k+1)}$$

that is
$$f^{(2k+1)}(0)=\frac{\Gamma \left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)(2k+1)!}{\sqrt{\pi } (2 k+1) \Gamma (k+1)}$$
and finally
$$f^{(2k+1)}(0)=\frac{4^k \Gamma \left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}{\pi }$$
while
$$f^{2k}(0)=0$$

Hope this is useful